# Minimizing tracking code

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for my app to track user activity. I need to track each VC and every time I should paste something like

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     
                                                  action:@"button_press"
                                                   label:@"play"
                                                   value:nil] build]];
```

It takes a lot of space when a usefull for me are only two parameters(action and label). I'm thinking about some macros for this function, but I still need to declare a tracker. How can I declare a tracker one time for whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default tracker was declared by GAI with `[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker]`, so you can use it for whole app.

You can implement your own function to track `ui_action` event with shorter code. Example: create new class AppTracking and write your tracking code here

**AppTracking.h**

```
/**
 *  @brief interface (AppTracking.h) file
 */
@interface AppTracking : NSObject

+ (void)sendGAIAction:(NSString *)action label:(NSString *)label;

@end
```

**AppTracking.m**

```
/**
 *  brief implementation (AppTracking.m) file
 */
@implementation AppTracking

+ (void)sendGAIAction:(NSString *)action label:(NSString *)label {
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"
                                                          action:action
                                                           label:label
                                                           value:nil] build]];
}

@end
```

And when track event

```
// call AppTracking function to track your event
[AppTracking sendGAIAction:@"button_press" label:@"play"];
```